# Product of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

I'm supposed to calculate :  $ F[\delta(x-a)](\nu)F[e^{i2\pi \nu x}](\nu)$

Since $F[\delta(x-a)] = e^{i 2\pi \nu a}F[\delta(x)] = e^{i 2\pi \nu a}$

it leaves : $$e^{i 2\pi \nu a}F[e^{i 2\pi \nu x}] = e^{i 2\pi \nu a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i 2\pi \nu x}e^{-i 2\pi \nu x}dx = e^{i 2\pi \nu a}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx$$

which does not converge...

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are transforming a function that has both $x$ and $\nu$ in it at the same time... please re-check. Anyway, the transform of $e^{2\pi ax}$ is the delta-function: you can see this from the inversion formula for Fourier transform, or by taking integral from $-M$ to $M$ and letting $M\to\infty$.

Comment: The integral definition of the Fourier transform applies only in some cases: for $L^1$ functions, and for finite complex measures. The transform is defined for many other functions and distributions too, but its definition has to be understood differently, via [passing the hat to test functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions). In practical terms, it can be computed by approximation: if $f$ is the distributional limit of $f_n$, then $\widehat f$ is  the distributional limit of $\widehat{ f_n}$.